# Entity class not found error

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, session-bean

Im new to java EJB ,Im getting this erro. i think its regarding entity class. can some one help me to fix this issue, thanks a lot.

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[registrationsServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet registrationsServlet threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Entity/Userdetailcb006116
    at com.themePark.servlets.registrationsServlet.processRequest(registrationsServlet.java:66)
    at com.themePark.servlets.registrationsServlet.doGet(registrationsServlet.java:88)

    ... more
```

here is the my servlet codes, it looks like ok to me but, compiler does'nt identify `Userdetailcb006116` as entity class. is there any way to make object of it or ?

```
import Entity.Userdetailcb006116;
import Sessions.Userdetailcb006116FacadeLocal;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class registrationsServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @EJB
    private Userdetailcb006116FacadeLocal userdetailcb006116Facade;


    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter()) {

        String fname = req.getParameter("fName");
        String lname = req.getParameter("lName");
        // here im getting error, although this entity class, compiler doesnt recognize as this a entity class i think 
        Userdetailcb006116 us = new Userdetailcb006116(fname, lname);
        userdetailcb006116Facade.create(us);

        RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
                rd.forward(req, resp);
        }
    }
```

Entity class code :

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author H4k3r
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERDETAILSCB006116")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Userdetailscb006116.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM Userdetailscb006116 u"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Userdetailscb006116.findByFname", query = "SELECT u FROM Userdetailscb006116 u WHERE u.fname = :fname"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Userdetailscb006116.findByLname", query = "SELECT u FROM Userdetailscb006116 u WHERE u.lname = :lname")})
public class Userdetailscb006116 implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "FNAME")
    private String fname;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "LNAME")
    private String lname;

    public Userdetailscb006116() {
    }

    public Userdetailscb006116(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (fname != null ? fname.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Userdetailscb006116)) {
            return false;
        }
        Userdetailscb006116 other = (Userdetailscb006116) object;
        if ((this.fname == null && other.fname != null) || (this.fname != null && !this.fname.equals(other.fname))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Entity.Userdetailscb006116[ fname=" + fname + " ]";
    }

}
```

facade code:

```
import Entity.Userdetailscb006116;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

/**
 *
 * @author H4k3r
 */
@Stateless
public class Userdetailscb006116Facade extends AbstractFacade<Userdetailscb006116> implements Userdetailscb006116FacadeLocal {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "cb006116_ThemePark-ejbPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public Userdetailscb006116Facade() {
        super(Userdetailscb006116.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: What server are you deploying on?

Comment: Where did you define the `Userdetailcb006116` class?

Comment: GlassFish 4.1 @MartijnBurger

Comment: Can you add the code for the Entity and the Façade?

Comment: It looks good to me. I'm using `@Inject` instead of `@EJB`. Can you try to add a beans.xml (if you did not allready) and change `@EJB` to `@Inject`?

Comment: you must have problem in your ear structure, entity class is missing there in runtime.